# Java Enterprise Application for Android

Tags: android, jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, enterprise

I'd like to make an application for Android which uses JEE6.
Is it possible to make an app which runs on a Glassfish (or other server) but with view in android app? 
Are there any frameworks or sth?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to make an API for your application in the JEE6 server. Then use whatever protocol you want to communicate through TCP/IP (I would strongly recommend you using HTTP for this).

Comment: You can have Android working as Client and on Server side you can implement what language or code you wish to.